# Java Generics Type Casting Necessary?

Tags: java, generics, types, casting

This is the code from my textbook:

```
Stack<String>[] a = (Stack<String>[]) new Stack[N];
```

My questions are:

1. Why is it "new Stack[N]"?
2. Why do you have to do type conversion on the new stack array created? I tried it with just

   ```
   Stack<String>[] a = new Stack[N];
   ```

and it compiled and ran fine. Even after pushing Strings into a and printing the pop method. Also, pushing a int in would immediately give me a compiler error so why is it necessary to type cast it to

```
Stack<String>[]
```

specifically?

Comment: Are you using Java 8?  Some things have gotten better with its generics system.

Answer (score 4):

You can not create arrays with parameterized type (see [Restrictions on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)). So you can not use `... = new Stack<String>[N]`.
Using `... = new Stack[N]` will work but you will have a warning for unchecked convertion (use `-Xlint` in javac to see the warning).

So the only proper way is to create the array with a raw parameter and then to apply a checked cast to the wanted type.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot. I read through the link but maybe it's repetition but it makes more sense now.

Comment: So what's the harm of NOT including a checked cast?

Comment: Not really harm. Unchecked convertion exists for compatibility reasons, with older pre-generics version of Java. Warnings remind dev that they should use genericity. See [Unchecked Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9).

Comment: ..or, in the case of arrays such as this: consider using a List instead. The [ArrayList] implementation itself handles similar code as that in the question but prevents the details, wrt arrays and generics, from leaking up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not sure what you mean by that question, but if you mean why **not** new `Stack<String>[N]` it is because java [arrays does not support parameterized array creation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)
2. Because of my answer in (1) the created array is not parameterized, but you are assigning it to a parameterized variable. And therefor the optional, but preferred checked cast.

Comment: Ahh I see. That's the terminology for it (not parameterized). So what's the danger if you do NOT assign it a parameterized variable and kept it as Stack[N]?

Comment: As @zer0chain mentioned, no danger really, just a warning, See [Unchecked Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9)

Answer (score 0):

First, as you've noticed, the cast is unnecessary. Without the cast, you will get an unchecked conversion warning (whereas with the cast, you will get an unchecked cast warning). The conversion between a raw type and a parameterized type can be made without an explicit cast (you will just get a warning).

If you are asking about why it's not possible to directly create an array of a parameterized type, this is because of how arrays in Java guarantee that, at runtime, they will never hold an element that is not an instance of the component type the array was created with. i.e. a runtime check is performed every time something is put into the array to check whether it is an instance of the component type of the array.

As you may know, generic type arguments don't exist at compile time, and it's not possible to check `instanceof` a parameterized type at runtime. It's only possible to check `instanceof` reified types. If an array could be created with a parametrized type, it would not be able to fulfill its contract of checking that everything put into it at runtime is an instance of that type. Someone relying on this guarantee of arrays will get unexpected results. Therefore, it will not allow you to do it. Creating an array with a raw type (which is what you did), or with a wildcard-parametrized type, however, is okay because those are reified types. Although you are using it as an array of a parameterized type, you did that through an unchecked conversion (with a warning) so you take responsibility for any safety issues that may result.